# Трафик сетевого интерфейса

Tags: сеть, linux

Как можно отслеживать загруженность виртуального сетевого интерфейса в линупсе?

Comment: C помощью снифферов( wireshark

Answer (score 2):

- Самое тривиальное решение (только общие объемы) — раз в некоторый интервал времени снимать показания счетчиков (октетов и/или пакетов) с интерфейса, и находить разницу. У старых ядрер нет какого-либо сисколла для получения 64-битных счетчиков, так что проще всего посмотреть в `/proc/net/dev`: `cat /proc/net/dev | awk '{ if (/^[[:space:]]*eth0:/) { print $2 + 10 } }'`

  У новых (примерно с двухлетней давности) можно общаться через netlink, используя `RTM_GETLINK` с `IFLA_STATS64`. Документация по [netlink](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html), увы, скудна и разрозненна, но примеры можно найти, скажем, в коде `iproute2`.
- Мониторинг происходящих соединений: `netstat -t -u -c`.

  Реализовано это через conntrack events. Создается netlink-сокет, который вступает в группу NF_CT_NETLINK, и там будет летать сообщения о изменениях в таблице соединений.
- Мониторинг пакетов (опционально, по соединениям): [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/), [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/)

  Реализуется, как правило, снифферами, через libpcap. По крайней мере, iftop, использует именно ее.

Comment: iptraf -- это из /proc/net/dev?

Comment: Нет, открывает «сырой» сокет и работает сниффером. Тут подробнее: [http://iptraf.seul.org/techinfo.html](http://iptraf.seul.org/techinfo.html).

В `/proc/net/dev` нет соединений вообще, там только статистика интерфейсов. Соединения, впрочем, можно найти в `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` (если conntrack не отключен, конечно).

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark, tcpdump. Если хочется просто графиков, то, например, через "Системный монитор" - в Ubuntu он так называется.